# Adding a breaker to an outside disconnect

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I live in a double wide mobile home, and I have a service pole with a disconnect and electric meter. There is a double 30 amp breaker in it with room to put another double breaker or two single breakers. I want to add a single pole, 20 amp breaker and run a wire underneath the disconnect to add an outside GFI plug. I see a ground bus, but not a neutral bus. What can I do?

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the panel?

Comment: I’m trying to lol

Comment: I hate to sound like a moron, but how in the hell do I put a picture on here?

Comment: It is actually not so obvious, unfortunately. So don't feel bad. Click Edit on the question. Click into the edit text box where you want to put the image. Click on the "mountain and sun" icon above the text box. You should get a pop-up with a place to paste a link or upload a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Since it has a disconnect, it is considered your main panel: your house panel is actually a sub-panel. In the main panel (and only there) neutral and ground are bonded. (Actually, in older installations where three-wire feeds were allowed, there is a neutral-ground bond in the sub too.)

Anyway, since it is the main panel, you are free to land a neutral on the ground/neutral (single) bus.

Comment: This is, most likely, the case and will get my up vote. A good pic from the OP would make me fell better about doing so, though.

Comment: You can't land the neutral on the ground bus! You *can* land ground on the neutral bus.